# JavaScript + Canvas: Write/Draw with stylus, ignore hand

Tags: html, canvas, drawing, pointer-events

I want to develop a web app (using HTML5 components like `<canvas>` and JavaScript libraries) that accepts user input from a stylus or a mouse but ignores touch input so you can safely rest your hand on the drawing canvas without it being interpreted as input unintentionally.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571021/is-it-possible-to-accept-stylus-input-on-a-html5-web-page) but specifically I'm curious about a clever concept to avoid unintentional input with existing HTML5/JavaScript APIs.

Is this possible and if, how?